# Google Analytics E-Commerce doesn't work with Magento 1.9.3.2

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics, google-api

If I add the GA tracking code in the Google API section, I receive an error message in Google Analytics. The message says that the "e-commerce data are not sent". How can I solve this issue?

I also try to install the free extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-1.html but if this extension is activated, the search box in my front-end doesn't work.

Comment: did you add any code in order success page???

Comment: No, I didn't add any code in success page.

Comment: refer this blog https://magecomp.com/blog/setup-google-analytics-magento-with-google-tag-manager/